# How to append data to elements attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

Having htmls like this,

```
<a class="testDiv" href="/link1"></a>
<a class="testDiv" href="/link2"></a>
```

I'm trying to append **`?param1=2`** to the `href` attributes of all `<a>` tags.

So that it should look like,

```
<a class="testDiv" href="/link1?param1=2"></a>
<a class="testDiv" href="/link2?param1=2"></a>
```

Something like this,

```
$(".testDiv").attr('href').append("?param1=2");
```

Is there any possible way for this?

Comment: Strange class name for anchor tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".testDiv").attr('href', function (_, currentHref) {
    return currentHref +"?param1=2"
});
```